# Disposal of keys and cards

Tags: resident-evil-code-veronica

Ever since I first played it on the PS2 I was wondering why the game asks you to discard of the keys or cards after you open all corresponding doors? Is there something to be unlocked if I keep all keys? It really bothers me to the point that I bought the game on PS4 to figure this out :D .

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but No

Many people asked the same question from RE1 until RE7 and even hold on to the keys (including me) hoping to unlock a secret but have not discovered such thing.

This topic is even discussed on the latest RE:

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/191629-resident-evil-7-biohazard/75027854?page=1